# Reducing matrix multiplication to squaring

Tags: matrices, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-complexity

I'm trying to solve problem 4.2-6 in the fourth edition of CLRS:

> Suppose that you have a $\Theta(n^\alpha)$-time algorithm for squaring $n \times n$ matrices, where $\alpha \geq 2$.  Show how to use that algorithm to multiply two different $n \times n$ matrices in $\Theta(n^\alpha)$ time.

I think that the authors might have forgotten the assumption that $AB=BA$, which enables the identity
$$A B = \frac{(A+B)^2-(A-B)^2}{2}.$$

Without the assumption, one elementary call (with no multiplications allowed) to `SQUARE` as a subroutine gives us a matrix of the form
$$(c I+aA+bB)^2=c^2 I+caA+cbB+caA+a^2A+abAB+cbB+abBA+b^2B^2 $$
and no matter what linear combination of these I try to form
$$\sum_i \alpha_i (c_i I+a_iA+b_iB)^2$$
I find that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same coefficient, and are thus indistinguishable.

Is it possible to reduce matrix multiplication to matrix squaring, in the non-commutative case? Or is that assumption necessary?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the question is a bit awkwardly phrased, which has lead you down this tangent. Note that if you have an $O(n^\alpha)$ algorithm for squaring $n \times n$ matrices, you _also_ have an $O(n^\alpha)$ algorithm for squaring $2n \times 2n$ matrices. That should be more useful.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Got it, thank you!

Comment: Yep by blocks you'll get $\begin{pmatrix} A&B\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix} A^2&AB\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$